# How to join multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to see what customers ordered what from a given manufacture.

I have theses tables (with columns):

- items (item_num, **order_num**, stock_num, **manu_code**, quantity, etc.)
- stock (stock_num, **manu_code**, **description**, unit_price, etc.)
- orders (**order_num**, order_date, **customer_num**, ship_instruct, etc.)
- customer (**customer_num**, fname, lname, company, address1, etc.)

This is my query right now, but I believe it is returning a cross product of some sort:

```
SELECT concat(c.fname," ", c.lname) AS fullname, s.description
FROM items i, stock s, customer c JOIN orders o 
ON o.customer_num=c.customer_num 
WHERE o.order_num=i.order_num AND i.manu_code = 'ANZ';
```

Which returns a big list (1000 lines) with lots of duplicate entires,

```
Anthony Higgens | baseball gloves
Anthony Higgens | baseball gloves
       .                 .
       .                 .
       .                 .
Kim Satifer     | running shoes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try grouping by the item id or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat(c.fname," ", c.lname) AS fullname, s.description
FROM customer c 
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_num = o.customer_num
INNER JOIN items i ON o.order_num = i.order_num
INNER JOIN stock s on s.stock_num = i.stock_num
WHERE i.manu_code = 'ANZ'
```

Comment: This returned too many rows. I just noticed items and stock both have a stock_num field, and changed last INNER JOIN to: INNER JOIN stock s on s.stock_num = i.stock_num

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT concat(c.fname," ", c.lname) AS fullname, s.description
    FROM customer c 
    INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_num = o.customer_num
    INNER JOIN items i ON o.order_num = i.order_num
    INNER JOIN stock s on s.stock_num = i.stock_num
    WHERE i.manu_code = 'ANZ';

Comment: @broinjc: yes, you're right... I didn't notice that field... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FROM items i, stock s, customer c` does a cartesian join of those three tables involved, but your `WHERE` does very little restriction on that cartesian join.

If  you do some more explicit joining you will grealy cut down on duplicates and more properly express what you are trying to do.  Use `INNER JOINS` and the correct join criteria instead of just listing all the tables after the `FROM`.  Example: (there are more such criteria, you would need to apply to the JOINS, but this is one example):  `INNER JOIN stock ON stack.manu_code = items.manu_code`.

Finally, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to further reduce duplicates.  But if you get your explicit `JOIN`s with JOIN criteria right, you should not have too many duplicates.

Comment: When I do a GROUP BY fullname, it shows what customers ordered 'ANZ' products, but all the descriptions read 'tennis racquet'. how can I concatenate descriptions of products they ordered?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
        SELECT          concat(a.fname, " ", a.lname ) as name
                        , d.description as desc
        FROM            CUSTOMER    a
        INNER JOIN      ORDERS      b
            on          a.customer_num = b.customer_num
        INNER JOIN      ITEMS       c
            on          b.order_num = c.order_num
        INNER JOIN      STOCK       d
            on          c.manu_code = d.manu_code
        where           c.manu_code like 'ANZ'
        group by        name,desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I think this is working now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat(c.fname," ", c.lname) AS fullname, s.description
FROM customer c 
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_num = o.customer_num
INNER JOIN items i ON o.order_num = i.order_num
INNER JOIN stock s on s.stock_num = i.stock_num
WHERE i.manu_code = 'ANZ';
```